# Find the possible values of momentum and the uncertainty of momentum for a given wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I have the wave function $\psi (x)  =A \sin (kx) $ for $- \infty <x< \infty$ and want to find all the possible values for momentum and $\Delta p$ . I have the solution but I can't understand it, my professor  says that the possible values are $p= \pm \hbar k$,can someone explain how do we get to this?  Also after finding $\langle p \rangle =0$ my professor finds $\langle p^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \hbar^2 k^2 + \frac{1}{2} \hbar^2 k^2$, can you explain that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. This is not trolling you, but writing in the variables that you do understand would help a lot, otherwise it's a bit  "do my  homework"

Comment: Do you know how to write $p$ as an operator?

Comment: I know that the possible values for $p$ comes from de Broglie formula, but I can't understand how $k$ and the plus minus sign appear.

Comment: $k=2\pi/\lambda$. The de Broglie wavelength only tells you the magnitude of the momentum, not its direction.

Comment: Also if I try to find $\langle p^2 \rangle$ with the usual way i. e.  $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \psi^*  \hbar^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi$ I can't compute the integral at those limits.

Comment: For $\langle p\rangle$, use this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301220/sine-function-as-a-momentum-eigenfunction.

Comment: For $\langle p^2\rangle$, hint: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi=k^2\psi$. Then assume $\psi$ is normalizable to ignore the integral.

Answer (score 2):

*I actually don't think this question makes much sense since your wave function $\psi(x)$ is not normalizable, but if you are willing to blindly accept (1) below then you can possibly understand the manipulations of your instructor.*

If you know that $\phi(x)=e^{ikx}$ describes a state of momentum $+k$, then it's no surprise that
$$
\psi(x)=A\sin(kx)=\frac{A}{2i}
\left(e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}\right)
$$
describes a state that is a superposition of $+k$ and $-k$.  The probability of getting $+k$ is the same as the probability of getting $-k$ since the coefficient $\vert A/2i\vert^2$ in front of each factor in the superposition is the same.

If the probability of obtaining $+k$ and $-k$ is the same, then the average value of $k$ will be $0$, irrespective of the constant $A$.

As to $\langle p^2\rangle$, note that $p^2\psi(x)=\hbar^2k^2\psi(x)$ so 
$$
\langle p^2\rangle =\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\hbar^2k^2\psi(x)}
{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)}=  
\hbar^2k^2
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)}
{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)}=\hbar^2k^2
$$
*assuming (somewhat blindly)* 
$$
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)}=1\, . \tag{1}
$$

You are right in being suspicious about the convergence of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\psi^*(x)\psi(x)$.